# How to make sure that the admob ads always appear on the bottom on the screen using xml only?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi
following link gives the xml of my android activity (activity.xml) and that of the admob  (admob.xml).How to make sure that the admob banner is always on the bottom of the display screen irrespective of the display created by the activity xml like in this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3e62.png ,Any suggestions on how to do this?

[activity.xml and admob.xml](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=nuMt3Bha)

Comment: What problem are you having? What is it doing now?

Comment: I placed the admob xml piece below the  <Button android:id="@+id/footer"...> and as expected the ads are always below it,so only when the user scrolls down then they can see the ads, i was trying to make the ads float on the bottom of the window/display/screen of the android, which is what I am asking?

Comment: How were we supposed to know that fro your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me!!!

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    ETC
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do is arrange the ad to be the last item in your layout. Then make something else in your layout, like a text view or something, and set the layout_weight to 1. This will make it take up the rest of the screen.

In the example you show there's a ListView with an adview below it. The ListView has it's layout_weight property set to 1 which makes it stretch to fill the rest of the screen.

Here's an example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"

          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a TextView"  />

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                                     android:layout_width="320"
                                     android:layout_height="50"
                                     android:gravity="center"
                                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```